# Question on using multiple SQL GROUP BY statements

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sum, group-concat

So ultimately I am trying to display the total number of times a pitcher has won the Cy Young award in my baseball league, and then the Season Year(s) they won it in, but sorted by League Name, since a pitcher could have won the award in different leagues in the same year.

This is how I'm trying to display the data: **Andrew Jones (4) - 2021, 2020 (18+); 2021 (28+); 2021 (38+)**, therefore I need the `Seasons` column to spit out the data like this: **2021, 2020 (18+); 2021 (28+); 2021 (38+)**

I have 3 mySQL tables (SEASON, LEAGUES, CY_YOUNG):

LEAGUES

```
| LEAGUE_ID | LEAGUE_NAME   |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 18+            |
| 2        | 28+            |
| 3        | 38+            |
| 4        | 48+            |
```

SEASONS

```
| SEASON_ID| LEAGUE_ID      | SEASON_YEAR |
| --------   | -------------| ----------- |
| 332        | 1            |   2021    |
| 333        | 2            |   2021    |
| 334        | 3            |   2021    |
| 335        | 4            |   2021    |
| 300        | 1            |   2020    |
| 301        | 2            |   2020    |
| 302        | 3            |   2020    |
| 303        | 4            |   2020    |
```

CY_YOUNG

```
| SEASON_ID  | PLAYER_NAME    | PLACE     |
| --------   | -------------- | ----------|
| 332        | Andrew Jones   |   1       |
| 332        | Mike Smith     |   2       |
| 333        | Andrew Jones   |   1       |
| 333        | Jacob Grimes   |   2       |
| 334        | Andrew Jones   |   1       |
| 334        | Travis Deane   |   2       |
| 300        | Andrew Jones   |   1       |
```

Here is my current SQL query:

```sql
   SELECT PLAYER_NAME, COUNT(ID) AS TotalWins, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(S.SEASON_YEAR,' (',L.LEAGUE_NAME) 
   ORDER BY S.SEASON_YEAR DESC SEPARATOR '), ') AS Seasons
   FROM CY_YOUNG
   JOIN SEASONS S ON S.SEASON_ID = CY_YOUNG.SeasonID
   JOIN LEAGUES L ON L.LEAGUE_ID = S.LEAGUE_ID
   WHERE CY_YOUNG.Place = 1
   GROUP BY PLAYER_NAME
   HAVING TotalWins > 1
   ORDER BY TotalWins DESC;
```

The `Seasons` column currently spits out like this:  **2021 (18+), 2020 (18+), 2021 (38+)** but I would like it to spit out like this: **2021, 2020 (18+); 2021 (28+); 2021 (38+)**. I know I'm close so any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think You need another group_concat within the concat as you first want to concatenate the leagues per year per player and then aggregate these per user only. You probably need to do the first group_concat in a subquery and use its outputs in the outer query.

Comment: Thank you Shadow, I know in theory that's what I need to do but for some reason I can't seem to get my brain to translate that in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT PLAYER_NAME, 
       SUM(counter) AS TotalWins,  
       GROUP_CONCAT(years, ' (', LEAGUE_NAME, ')' ORDER BY LEAGUE_NAME, years) AS Seasons
FROM (
  SELECT PLAYER_NAME, L.LEAGUE_NAME,
         COUNT(*) counter,
         GROUP_CONCAT(S.SEASON_YEAR ORDER BY S.SEASON_YEAR DESC) AS years
  FROM CY_YOUNG C
  JOIN SEASONS S ON S.SEASON_ID = C.SEASON_ID
  JOIN LEAGUES L ON L.LEAGUE_ID = S.LEAGUE_ID
  WHERE C.Place = 1
  GROUP BY C.PLAYER_NAME, L.LEAGUE_NAME
) t  
GROUP BY PLAYER_NAME
HAVING TotalWins > 1
ORDER BY TotalWins DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fbb2437300257930b209a67ae7e6129f).

Comment: YOU are my HERO!  Thank you so much!